# Android contentprovider insert takes a lot of time

Tags: android, sql, insert, android-contentprovider

I made my own contentprovider where I put a lot of data in at once with multiple inserts.

The app will receive the data from an external source and at this moment I receive about 30 items (therefor 30 times an insert).

Now I noticed that this takes a lot of precious time (about 3 seconds, 100ms on each insert).

How can I improve the speed of the contentprovider? I already tried to bulkInsert them all together but them it will take up to 5 sec.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use content providers with Android 2.1 or lower, don't expect to do a bulk insert in less than 1 or 2 sec (even with transactions). The SQLite implementation was very slow.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using 2.2. So that should be ok.

Comment: sometimes the problem may be with insert statements. To check that you can use SQLiteBrowser open your database there and execute same insert statements whether it is taking time there also?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

wrap all that in `insertBulk` into transactions.

Example:

```
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = mDB.getWritableDatabase();
    sqlDB.beginTransaction();
    try {

        for (ContentValues cv : values) {
            long newID = sqlDB.insertOrThrow(table, null, cv);
            if (newID <= 0) {
                throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
            }
        }
        sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        numInserted = values.length;
    } finally {
        sqlDB.endTransaction();
    }
```

`bulkInsert` does not use transactions by default, since the default behavior just calls `insert`:

> Override this to handle requests to insert a set of new rows, or the default implementation will iterate over the values and call insert(Uri, ContentValues) on each of them.

Comment: In that fully working sample, query the `Uri` in order to provide a suitable `table` variable.

Comment: Thanks man! This really solved it! Instead of 3 seconds it inserted it in 110ms.

Comment: You're welcome. That sample is actually from a code I have. :-)

Answer (score 3):

doing the inserts in a transaction greatly improves the speed, since only one write to the actuall database takes place:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // do the inserts
    db.setTransactionSuccessful()
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

I was once experimenting trying to improve the write speed of about ~2000 writes, and this was the only big improvement I found.

Doing `db.setLockingEnabled(false)` i think gave about 1% improvement, but then you must also make sure no other threads write to the db. Removing redundant indexes can also give a minor boost if the table is huge.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.